# Figuring out tags

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the difference between new-players (5 uses), new-gm(3 uses), newb-advice (1 use) and beginner (1 use)?

Answer (score 2):

newb-advice and beginner seem the same. I recommend going with beginner (its a real word for one). new-players and new-gm are seem specific enough to stand on their own.

Comment: I retagged the newb-advice to new-gm because that was more appropriate.  The one tagged beginner is an interesting case, it's not about a new gm or new player it's about being new to a game or setting, if I were tag god I might call that setting-intro or something like that.  Beginner's pretty vague if it covers that case.

Comment: After a while these will sort themselves out, as we get more tag wiki entries filled out to explain their application, and as the folksonomy shakes out and the "winner" tags float to the top in usage. (`[newb-advice]` will likely never get widely used, for example. We'll have to see how `[beginner]` gets used, if at all.)